# Detect notification area background color?

Tags: c#, windows, notifications

I have to say I am a bit shocked the answer to this problem isn't easier to find.  I have an application that creates a notification tray icon.  When I am running my app on Windows 10 the notification area background color is black.  So I am using a white version of my logo for contrast.  Running the same program on Windows 7 the taskbar background is dark, but the notification popup has a white background.  Thus using my white icon doesn't work?

My first thought was to determine if I am on Windows 10 and if I wasn't to use a blue version of my icons.  Sounds simple enough until you try to detect the OS version.  For some reason Microsoft has decided that the OSVersion information will just return the Windows 8 version number from now on (if you are on Windows 10)?!?! Seriously?  The suggestions to detect Windows 10 are to look at registry keys, or make unsafe calls to kernel level api's?

Other application developers have had to run into this issue.  What is the solution?  How do you managed your notification tray icons when they have to work when on a white background and black?  I would prefer not to make the blue images background white, since the box around the icon won't look very nice.

Comment: I'm interested in the solution to your question, but... in the meantime, you could just add a thin black border for your white icon, and it should look fine either way.

Comment: Like DJ says, add a 1-pixel black border and inside that add a 1-pixel white border or something like that. Any colour logo looks ok against any colour background. You could even swap the black and white on some edges for a 3D effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will give that a try.  I was looking at how Dropbox does it, because I noticed their icon is white.  After some testing it looks like they do what you are talking about.